# Caculating average from some data with python 2.7.x

Tags: python-2.7

I have been practicing python to learn how to code and I'm making python program that calculates averages from numbers which are put in by users.
Here is codes

```
avg_input=0.0
import sys
input_list=sys.argv[1:]

for avg in input_list :
    avg_input += avg

avg_input /= len(input_list)
avg_input
```

and this is error messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exfor3.py", line 30, in <module>
    avg_input += avg
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sys.argv is a list of strings. You need to convert these to numbers before adding them. Use:

```
avg_input += float(avg)
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I can fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to add a float value to a string. You will either need to convert the variable `avg` into a float using the `float()`function or change the variable type for `avg`

Comment: Thank you for your support.^^